# Bootstrap dismiss on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following input, which appears on click and disappears on the next click:

```
<a href="#;" class="asset_info" data-asset_id="{{ asset.pk }}" 
   data-toggle="focus" tabindex="0" data-placement="left" data-trigger="focus"
>Hello</a>
```

However, I only want the popup to disappear on the next click **if the person is not clicking on the box**. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $(".asset_info").click(function() {
    el = $(this);
    asset_id = el.data('asset_id');
    $.post("/get_asset_info/", {'asset_id': asset_id}, function(response) {
        el.unbind('click').popover({
        content: response,
        html: true,
        delay: {show: 200, hide: 100}
      }).popover('show');
    });
  });

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
$('html').on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).closest('.popover').length) {
     $('.popover').each(function(){
        $(this.previousSibling).popover('hide');
    });
  }
});
```